# Regex match two words and not match other

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex to match follow conditions:

> ( (iphone|ipod) OR ( android AND mobile AND (NOT gt-p) ) )

Would someone help me?

Edit:

With the help in comments I've the follow code:

```
iphone|ipod|(android(?!.*?gt-p)(?:\s*mobile))?
```

It is the same regex with more on group to android alone not match... is it correct?

Comment: please post what you've tried. "could you develop this for me" questions aren't often met warmly on this site because it doesn't show intent to learn. if you post the code that you are working with - even if you think you are way off - you'll certainly get an answer you are looking for and probably improve your regex skills in the process

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm a little bad in english.

Comment: @RodrigoMonteiroFerreira - no problem and no need to apologize :). just people normally get better answers on this site when they include their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're after:

```
iphone|ipod|android(?!.*?gt-p)(?:\s*mobile)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/xT8rD4/1

It will allow `android` and `android mobile` not followed by `gt-p`.  If it should only allow `android mobile`, it's an easy fix.

Comment: Really thank you!

My regex cant get when has only the word "android"...

I changed for:

iphone|ipod|(android(?!.*?gt-p)(?:\s*mobile))?

Is it correct?

Comment: @RodrigoMonteiroFerreira - Move the final question mark into the final parenthesis like so: iphone|ipod|(android(?!.*?gt-p)(?:\s*mobile)?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my offering for you

```
(^((?!gt-p).)*mobile((?!gt-p).)*android((?!gt-p).)*$)|(^((?!gt-p).)*android((?!gt-p).)*mobile((?!gt-p).)*$)|iphone|ipad
```

It matches for anything with "ipad" or "iphone" or ("android" and "mobile" in any order, as long it doesn't also contain "gt-p")

https://regex101.com/r/dR5rE4/1